# How to use external initializer in for loop and setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please look at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7hch6s

```
function main(): void {
  let loopIndex: number = 2;
  let actions: string[] = ["dance", "walk", "run", "sit", "kick"];
  for (; loopIndex < 5; loopIndex++) {
    doAction(actions[loopIndex]);
    window.setTimeout(() => doAction(actions[loopIndex]), 1000);
  }
}
function doAction(action: string) {
  console.log("action is " + action);
}
main();
/////////
The output in the console is
action is run
action is sit
action is kick
action is undefined
action is undefined
action is undefined
```

I get the three undefineds where I want the values of run sit kick to print in the last three lines in the console.
Is this a scope problem? I tried the bind method. But, I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time the first doAction inside of setTimeout is called loopIndex is already equal to 5 and actions[5] is unknown.

The simplest method to solve this would be moving the variable initialization into the for loop. This works because of the let keywords scoping rules:

```
for (let loopIndex: number = 2; loopIndex < 5; loopIndex++) {
    doAction(actions[loopIndex]);
    window.setTimeout(() => doAction(actions[loopIndex]), 1000);
}
```

or you could use a closure:

```
function main(): void {
  let loopIndex: number = 2;
  let actions: string[] = ["dance", "walk", "run", "sit", "kick"];
  for (; loopIndex < 5; loopIndex++) {
    doAction(actions[loopIndex]);
    delayDoAction(actions[loopIndex]);
  }
}

function delayDoAction(action: string) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    doAction(action)
  }, 1000);
}

function doAction(action: string) {
  console.log("action is " + action);
}
main();
```

or finding some other way of incrementing the index inside of the doAction function.

Comment: Thank you for  suggesting a closure. It seems to work. I am  going to have to  study them for a while. I don't agree with the first sentence  in your post.

Comment: @rickz to demonstrate the first statement you can add console.log(startIndex) in the setTimeout callback before doAction and you will see 5 printed 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.  I tried  your last suggestion. I get Error: startIndex is not defined   .  I will keep studying closures.  I  find them hard to understand.

Comment: To make  my question clearer, I renamed startIndex to loopIndex.  I  used your  suggestion   in my Stackblitz  and it works there. I also changed my Angular project to use a closure. It works now.  I am still studying  closures. I still don't understand why it works.

Comment: You are right. Your  first  statement is correct.  I am sorry that I doubted you. But,  I would change  the name of your function  from delayDoAction to  capturedAction.  That would describe the  closure functionality.